# Solvable Field Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, solvable-groups

I have a question about a step in a proof from Lang's "Algebra": Thm. 7.2 (page 292). Here the excerpt & tagged problem:

[image]

During the proof the author defines $F:= k(\zeta)$ where $\zeta$ is the primitive $m$-root. Obviously $F/k$ is clearly abelian since $Gal(F,k)=(\mathbb{Z}/m)^*$.

My question is why does it imply that then the compositum $KF$ is ***solvable*** over $F$? (definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group)

By assumption $K$ was finite solvable over $k$. Is there a way to derive solvability of $KF$ over $F$ from this?

Answer (score 2):

Since $K/k$ is finite Galois, $KF/F$ is finite Galois.

Also, $\text{Gal}(KF/F)$ is embedded in $\text{Gal}(K/k)$, where the embedding is restricting automorphisms in $\text{Gal}(KF/K)$ to $E$.

Since $\text{Gal}(K/k)$ is solvable, so is $\text{Gal}(KF/K)$.
That is, $KF/K$ is solvable.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. two questions: Which argument have you concretely used to see that $KF/F$ is Galois? The long way might be to show that if $K,F$ are Galois over $k$ then also their compositum $KF$ (over $k$) and therefore also Galois over $F$. Do you have this argument in mind or is there another more "witty" one? 

Secondly: why is $Gal(KF/F)$ to $Gal(K/k)$ injective?

Comment: @KarlPeter Separable + normal implies Galois. $K = k(a), KF = F(a)$, when restricting $\sigma \in Gal(KF/F)$ to $K$ you still know $\sigma(a)$