# Compositum $FL/F$ Galois if $L/K$ Galois

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

This question arises from following thread of mine: [Solvable Field Extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277761/solvable-field-extension)

Let $K$ a field, $F /K$ an algebraic and $L/K$ a Galois extension of $K$. Why is the compositum $FL/F$ Galois?

My attempts:

I have only solved the case: $L= K(a)$. In this case I claim that $FL=F(a)$: "$\supseteq$" is obvious and "$\subseteq$" because $a \in F(A)$ implies $L \subset F(a)$ and $F \subset F(a)$ is obvious.

Remark: this argument can be extended to the case that $L/K$ is ***finite*** Galois: Then if $L= K(a,b,..., i)$ then $FL= F(a,b,..., i)$ similary,right?

Denote $p_a ^K, p_a ^F$ the minimal polynomials of $a$ in $K[X]$ and $F[X]$. Obvoiusly $p_a ^F  \vert  p_a ^K$ so $a$ is sparable over $F$ and $p_a ^F  $ splits in $FL$ since $  p_a ^K$ splits in $L$.

How to handle the general case $L /K$ Galois?

By the way: is there a more conventional way to argue than the way I described above?

Comment: $L/K$ is the union of all  finite Galois sub-extensions $L'/K$, by your proof, $FL'/F$ is a finite Galois extension, then so do ( can prove by definition ) their union $FL/F$.

Comment: It is always the case that $L = K(a)$ with $a = (a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ and it works exactly the same as for $n=1$. Equivalently $L$ is $f \in K[x]$'s splitting field and $FL$ is $f \in F[x]$'s splitting field. Also you should know the primitive element theorem : that $L/K$ separable implies we can take $n=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an automorphism $\alpha$ of $FL$ that fixes $F$. Then it fixes $K$ in particular, so as $L/K$ is normal,  $\alpha(L)=L$. From this you conclude that $\alpha(FL)=FL$ and so $FL/F$ is normal.

Regarding separability, you sketched the argument yourself.

Comment: You mean that you take an automorphism $α$ of $FL$ that fixes $F$ not $L$, right? Because we wan't to have that $FL/F$ is normal not $FL/L$

Comment: I confused the roles of F and L, corrected it